# Additional legend in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, distribution

I have a problem where the legend of my `ggplot()` does not appear. Here's my code:

```
plot_bt <- ggplot(NULL, aes(x, v1)) + 
  geom_line(data = nig_bt_1, colour = "black") +
  geom_line(data = nig_bt_2, colour = "blue") +
  geom_line(data = nig_bt_3, colour = "red") + 
  labs(x = "X", y = "Probability")
```

I tried to make a legend inside this graph but I could not do it. It just does not appear. I try to make a plot of three different types of NIG distribution. In nig_bt_1 etc. I have my values. Those three densities appear but the legend doesn't. I tried the `scale_color_manual` function too with no success.

Thank you very much.

```
x <- seq(-7.5,7.5,0.001)
nig_bt_1 <- data.frame(x ,v1 = dnig(x, param = pr_bt_1))
nig_bt_2 <- data.frame(x ,v1 = dnig(x, param = pr_bt_2))
nig_bt_3 <- data.frame(x ,v1 = dnig(x, param = pr_bt_3))
```

Comment: it is usually better to combine the data into a single object and let ggplot handle everything

Comment: I had a problem because I was not able to create multiple plot in the way you write.

Comment: @FNTE please post example how `nig_bt_1`, `nig_bt_2`, `nig_bt_3` look like

Comment: I've edited my post.

Comment: @FNTE what's `dnig`, `pr_bt_1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this:

```
plot_bt <- ggplot(NULL, aes(x, v1)) + 
  geom_line(data = nig_bt_1, aes(colour = "a")) +
  geom_line(data = nig_bt_2, aes(colour = "b")) +
  geom_line(data = nig_bt_3, aes(colour = "c")) + 
  labs(x = "X", y = "Probability") +
  scales_color_manual(values= c("a" = "black", "b" = "blue", "c" = "red"))
```

A guide can only depict mappings you've defined using `aes`. The ggplot2 way is of course to first combine the data and use a grouping variable.

Comment: Thank you so much, now I see my mistake.